# Редирект .htaccess с www на без www в 1С Битрикс

Tags: редирект, битрикс

Сайт на 1С Битрикс, работает комплексный компонент новостей, настроены ЧПУ. В .htaccess 1С Битрикс прописывает стандартный набор правил:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

я добавляю правила для склейки доменов. Нужен редирект с www на без www

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.advokat-norec\.ru
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://advokat-norec.ru/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

пока хожу по "физически" существующим страницам, всё в порядке, стоит перейти на страницу новости, ссылку на которую формирует компонент, меня кидает на /bitrix/urlrewrite.php. Как поправить не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>С .htaccess все в порядке, копать в сторону urlrewrite.php.</strike>
Попробуйте правила для склейки поставить сразу после RewriteEngine On

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы всегда можете оставлять комментарии под **своими** вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/60335)

Comment: По-моему я погорячился с ответом.